# When I want to create gem but got mirror effect

Tags: transparency, glass

I follow a tuto on Youtube about make a Gemstone, and the author have a material like:
[image]

And I Remake the material in my Blender then add it to my object, but I got a mirror effect in some faces:[image]

I really do not know why.

Comment: 1 difference that I see is that you changed IOR to 2 and he left it at 1.45, which may change reflections slightly... also are you using the same HDRI as the author of the tutorial? Because his gem is a mirror as well, but it has more edges, it is smooth, not sharp as yours and I can definitely see some studio lights or something on his gemstone (or maybe those are windows in dark room

Comment: I'm with @MikoCG here. Another thing is, he has a _Density_ of 20 in the _Principled Volume_ where you have 5. Even if the densities were the same, it also makes a difference if his gemstone is 1 m in size and yours is 100 m. Also is his absorption color less saturated than yours and a bit brighter (_Value_ 0.8 where you have 0.7).

Comment: thank you @GordonBrinkmann. Your suggestions are really useful. So is it fact that a glass mat could create this mirror-like faces? I upload this question mainly because  this is paradox with my intuition.

Comment: thank you @MikoCG. Your suggestions are really useful. So is it fact that a glass mat could create this mirror-like faces? I upload this question mainly because this is paradox with my intuition.

Comment: @shibi Yes of course it's possible that a glass material can create mirror-like faces. Ask yourself: can glass (in real life) mirror something? Yes, it can. The lower the angle, the stronger the reflection.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thanks Agian! I'll do more observation and paractice in Blender to see the unification among reality and virtual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of values are not the same, try copying the video exactly. Also because the shape is different, and the youtuber seems to have used a few modifiers. This may have an affect on the end look of the object.

Comment: cause the tuto didnot show the hdri and lights so I set those values by myself, I'll try more combinations of those properties, thank you again.